Not showing the products initially
I have HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files, and I am trying to create a product browser. There are three categories of products - Electronics, Clothing, Books - and I want to create a wishlist where the user can add their products.
The problem is that when I run the HTML file, the products are not showing. However, when I click the button on any category, I'm showing the product category but I want to show initial three products.
HTML code:
<body>
    <h1>Product Browser </h1>

    <div id="categories">
        <button onclick="filterProducts('electronics')">Electronics</button>
        <button onclick="filterProducts('clothing')">Clothing</button>
        <button onclick="filterProducts('books')">Books</button>
    </div>


    <div id="product-list">
    </div>

    <div id="wishlist">
        <h2>Wishlist</h2>
        <div id="wishlist-items"></div>
        <p id="wishlist-summary"></p>
        <button onclick="clearWishlist()">Clear Wishlist</button>
    </div>

    <script src="LabExamScript.js"></script>

JAVASCRIPT code:
const products = [
    { id: 1, name: "Smartphone", category: "electronics", image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" },
    { id: 2, name: "Jeans", category: "clothing", image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" },
    { id: 3, name: "Magazine", category: "books", image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" }
];




let whishlist = []


function filterProducts(category) {
    const productList = document.getElementById("product-list");
    productList.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous content

    // Filter products by category and display them
    const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => product.category === category);
    filteredProducts.forEach(product => {
        const productCard = document.createElement("div");
        productCard.classList.add("product-card");

        productCard.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}">
            <h2>${product.name}</h2>
            <button onclick="addToWishlist(${product.id})">Add to Wishlist</button>
        `;
        
        productList.appendChild(productCard);
    });
}

Initial Output:

and when I click any product button:


filterProducts is only called when you click a category button

The issue is most probably that your filterProducts function is only called when you click a category button. To display initial products, you need to call it once when the page loads.
// Call filterProducts on page load to display initial products
window.attachEvent('onload', function (){
    filterProducts();
});

function addToWishlist(productId) {
    // Wishlist logic
}

function clearWishlist() {
    // Wishlist logic
}


Change your filter to support search for all kinds of products:
And call it on page load.


const products = [
    { id: 1, name: "Smartphone", category: "electronics", image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" },
    { id: 2, name: "Jeans", category: "clothing", image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" },
    { id: 3, name: "Magazine", category: "books", image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" }
];


let whishlist = []

function filterProducts(category) {
    const productList = document.getElementById("product-list");
    productList.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous content

    // Filter products by category and display them
    const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => (!category) ||(product.category === category));
    filteredProducts.forEach(product => {
        const productCard = document.createElement("div");
        productCard.classList.add("product-card");

        productCard.innerHTML = `
            <img src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}">
            <h2>${product.name}</h2>
            <button onclick="addToWishlist(${product.id})">Add to Wishlist</button>
        `;
        
        productList.appendChild(productCard);
    });
}




window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    filterProducts();
});
    <h1>Product Browser </h1>

    <div id="categories">
        <button onclick="filterProducts('electronics')">Electronics</button>
        <button onclick="filterProducts('clothing')">Clothing</button>
        <button onclick="filterProducts('books')">Books</button>
    </div>


    <div id="product-list">
    </div>

    <div id="wishlist">
        <h2>Wishlist</h2>
        <div id="wishlist-items"></div>
        <p id="wishlist-summary"></p>
        <button onclick="clearWishlist()">Clear Wishlist</button>
    </div>



Or if you prefer, you can pass a specific category as the default choice on page load.

Functions should have a single function in OOP.

// Filter products by category and display them

This should be split into 1) filter the products and 2) display them because it means the code remains simple and can be reused and extended e.g. sorting items


const products = [
    { id: 1, name: "Smartphone", category: "electronics", image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" },
    { id: 2, name: "Jeans", category: "clothing", image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" },
    { id: 3, name: "Magazine", category: "books", image: "https://via.placeholder.com/150" }
];

let wishlist = []


function filterProducts(category) {
    // Filter products by category
    const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => product.category === category);
    displayProducts(filteredProducts);
}

function allProducts() {
  displayProducts(products);
}

function displayProducts(filteredProducts) {
    //and display them
    const productList = document.getElementById("product-list");
    productList.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous content

    filteredProducts.forEach(product => {
      const productCard = document.createElement("div");
      productCard.classList.add("product-card");

      productCard.innerHTML = `
          <img src="${product.image}" alt="${product.name}">
          <h2>${product.name}</h2>
          <button onclick="addToWishlist(${product.id})">Add to Wishlist</button>
      `;

      productList.appendChild(productCard);
  });
}
<body onload="allProducts();">
    <h1>Product Browser </h1>

    <div id="categories">
        <button onclick="filterProducts('electronics')">Electronics</button>
        <button onclick="filterProducts('clothing')">Clothing</button>
        <button onclick="filterProducts('books')">Books</button>

    </div>


    <div id="product-list">
    </div>

    <div id="wishlist">
        <h2>Wishlist</h2>
        <div id="wishlist-items"></div>
        <p id="wishlist-summary"></p>
        <button onclick="clearWishlist();">Clear Wishlist</button>
    </div>

<script src="LabExamScript.js"></script>
</body>



